# Microsoft Teams No Calling Tab

Tags: microsoft-teams

We are trying to implement Microsoft Teams Calls (we've been using Teams), that was recently [released](https://techcommunity.microsoft.com/t5/Microsoft-Teams-Blog/Intelligent-Communications-takes-the-next-step-with-calling-in/ba-p/136185).  Some of our staff now has calling plans, Office 365 Enterprise E5.  Of this staff, some now have a Calls tab on the left, but one does not.

[image]

[image] [image]

The one with no Calls tab updated Teams to the latest version (1.1.00.1155 x64), but still no Calls tab.  However, they do see Call options in the Settings section and they can receive calls in Teams.  Any suggestions or recommended ways to troubleshoot this further to determine why the Calls tab is not showing for the one user?

[image]

Comment: 1) please don't post only pictures of errors or code, 2) debugging help is off topic here, 3) tagging this only microsoft-teams means very few people will see it although I'm not sure what other tag you could use to improve this. Maybe a case for SuperUser forum.

Comment: I posted narrative prior to the images, I thought the images would be helpful. I agree SO is not the ideal site. I leaned toward posting on ServerFault, but there was no Teams tag there, so went with SO.  I looked a bit ago at SuperUser, but no tag there either.  But I'm open to either of those if you think they still may be more helpful even though no tags exist.

Comment: @Gilligan - this shouldn't happen. I've reported this to our Calling team and we want to troubleshoot. Please send me an email: billbl@microsoft.com.

Comment: Thanks Bill, will do.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

We have contacted you offline to resolve this problem, which appears to be a configuration issue. This is indeed not a coding issue.

Comment: Yes, the issue has been resolved.  There was a forced sync of our tenant done to fix a configuration / state issue for this user.  Thank you!